# Import jar class into java program

Tags: java, class, jar

I have this servlet program and an external .jar file (written by someone else) that I want to call to. I basically want to import one of the classes located in the jar file because it has a method that I need to call. Is this possible?

Currently, the previous programmer was able to call to the class (I want) by simply:

```
import Validator.validate;
```

Now the name of the .jar is

> BugValidator.jar

I've tried implementing the above code to no sucees, is there a specific location the file needs to be in? I am using netbeans 7.1, so should I add it to the filepath?

Comment: Did you add the jar file to your classpath ?

Comment: i guess not, but I added it to the WEB-INF/lib folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy the JAR file into `WEB-INF/lib`. The container will automatically add it to the classpath if it's in this folder.

**[EDIT]** Inside Netbeans, you'll have to add the JAR manually. Right click on "Libraries" -> "Add JAR/Folder..."

Comment: how can i check to see if it is in my classpath  because I added it to the WEB-INF/lib folder and import Validator.validate highlights as an error

Comment: `Validator.validate` sounds odd. Package names should start with "com" or "org" and they should be lowercase. Delete `.validate` and press the two keys Ctrl+Space with the cursor right after `Validator`

Comment: it comes up with no suggestions.... the BugValidator.jar has (other than the manifest) only a Validator folder, no com or org/Validator

Comment: So there is a folder inside which is called `Validator` and inside the folder is a file `validator.class`? (not the case of the first letter!) Sounds really odd. Any Java IDE will litter this code with warnings about the names used.

Comment: ya exactly, i'm wondering if I should just add the .class to my src folder and just be done with it

Comment: This sound like you should not use this code - if the guy broke even the most basic rules of Java development, I'd wonder what other rules he broke... anyway. WEB-INF/lib is the way to go. What container/app server do you use?

Comment: Okay. It's an appache tomcat server

Comment: Do you get the error in your IDE or when running your app inside tomcat? If it's in the IDE, which one do you use?

Comment: it's in the IDE, i haven't uploaded it to the server just yet. I use netbeans 7.1

Comment: In that case, you probably have to add the JAR to the classpath manually. Tomcat will pick it up but Netbeans might not know that your project is a web app. See here how to add a JAR to a project: http://monkeybars.rubyforge.org/tutorials/netbeans.html